# Excel VBA code to scrape URLs, two different error codes

Tags: excel, vba, url

Again, very new to coding, any insight appreciated. See code below, am happy to provide more if that helps solve the issue. I've marked [issue] next to the lines that are generating the error messages.

```
Set xRng = Application.InputBox("Please select the keyword range", "Google Search Macro", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
If xRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
xLastRow = xRng.Rows.Count

Set xRng = xRng(1)

For i = 0 [issue] To xLastRow - 1 
tempStr = xRng.Offset(i).Value
tempStr = Replace(tempStr, " ", "+")
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & tempStr

Set nameCell = xRng.Offset(i, 1)
Set linkCell = xRng.Offset(i, 2)

Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
request.Open "GET", url, False
request.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
request.send

returnStr = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
returnPage.body.innerHTML = returnStr [issue]
```

The first error message that comes up is "Compile error: For control variable already in use" and it highlights "For i = 0."

The second error message that comes up is "Compile error: Expected End Sub" and it highlights "returnStr."

Comment: I guess this is a bigger project, the lack of code won't let us help. Your first error means that you have some `For i`before the one you are showing us without a `Next i`. The second error means that, you have code outside a  Sub.

Comment: @Damian will post more code, one sec.

Comment: Still not enough, post the full code for that `Sub` and remove the `On Error Resume Next` errors will happen but you won't notice at all.

Comment: @Damian full code available

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is _not error handling_, it's ___error ignoring___. If you want to use it for an obj that you expect may return `Nothing`, then fine - but make sure you reset it to `On Error GoTo 0` or another method of managing your errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, your code sorted.

You were missing a declaration, to avoid this I recommend using `Option Explicit` on the top of your module which will forece you to declare all your variables.

You were missing the `Next i` to close the loop and the `End Sub` to close the procedure:

```
Option Explicit
Sub URLPull()

    Dim searchRange As Range
'    Dim nameCell As Range 'not used
'    Dim linkCell As Range 'not used
    Dim url As String
    Dim returnStr As String
    Dim tempStr As String
    'Dim i As Long, xLastRow As Long 'no need for them using For Each loop
    Dim request As Object
    Dim returnPage As New HTMLDocument
    Dim returnSiteName As Variant
    Dim returnLink As Variant
    Dim xRng As Range 'this was missing
    Dim C As Range 'to loop through the xRng

    'On Error Resume Next delete this, this is for error handle

    Set xRng = Application.InputBox("Please select the keyword range", "Google Search Macro", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
    If xRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'    xLastRow = xRng.Rows.Count
'
'    Set xRng = xRng(1)

    Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP") 'QHarr comment

    For Each C In xRng 'this way you loop through all the cells in your range
        tempStr = C 'this is the cell value
        tempStr = Replace(tempStr, " ", "+")
        url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & tempStr 'if you get no results, check here the tempStr value
        'You are not using these:
'        Set nameCell = xRng.Offset(i, 1)
'        Set linkCell = xRng.Offset(i, 2)
        request.Open "GET", url, False
        request.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        request.send
        returnStr = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
        returnPage.body.innerHTML = returnStr
    Next C 'this was missing

End Sub 'this was missing
```

Comment: Thanks! No more errors, but when I run the macro and input the cell range to do the macro on, no URLs come up. I've made sure that the macro is being performed in the correct sheet, I have Internet Explorer open to Google, but still no results pulled.

Comment: change this: `tempStr = xRng.Offset(i).Value` for `tempStr = Thisworkbook.Sheets("SheetName").Cells(i, "columnletter")`

Comment: Move this CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP") out of the loop. You only need to create once

Comment: @Damian with the new code, compile error message "variable not defined" comes up and highlights "i" in "Set nameCell = xRng.Offset(i, 1)

Comment: @chundychang check my code now. Thanks QHarr for your comment.

Comment: @Damian question- are `xLastRow = xRng.Rows.Count` and `Set xRng = xRng(1)` gone in your edited code?

Comment: Yes, you don't need them, when you set your `xRng` and use `For Each C in xRng` means that the loop will go through all the cells inside `xRng` so there is no need to find the `LastRow` nor setting a starting point.

Comment: @Damian so i used your code, still zero results. When I run the macro, it'll ask me for the cell range, I put in just the data in column a, nothing. I'll increase it to columns a and b, nothing.

Comment: Actually- I just found the full body of the code and it turns out there were a LOT of missing parts. It's working fully now, thanks for all the help though!

Comment: Glad it helped, please @chundychang consider marking this answer as correct if it is, so others might find it.